# I cannot locate my Rdio.com client ID

Tags: rdio

I've only just begun looking at development of Rdio apps and such, but every tutorial I have looked at asks to replace

script src="https://www.rdio.com/api/api.js?client_id='myidhere'

I have been trying to figure out how to get the ID for my application, but I am unable to find it. How do I get it?

Comment: What api are you using? Web service or playback?

Comment: I hadn't applied for the beta yet. It turns out that their JS api is still in Beta, so you'll have to apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the [beta JavaScript API](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rdio-api/_UlW2Oc6Dvc/uGhwZUwxSesJ), you'll have to apply for an API key during the beta period.

Comment: Thanks, devin. I applied; hacking has begun.